# Two mat-gird-list is getting overlapped when placed in row

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Hi i am using two dynamic material grid list, but when trying to place them, second mat-gird-list is getting overlapped-on first mat-gird-list when ever in the grid list increases.

Below is the css code,

```css
.my-grid-list-first {
      padding-bottom: calc( 1 * ((15.3333% - 0.666667px) * 1) + 0px + 0px) !important;
    }

.my-grid-tile-first {
  width: calc((20% - 0.75px) * 1 + 0px) !important;
  padding-top: calc((4.3333% - 0.666667px) * 1 + 0px) !important;
}

.my-grid-list-second {
  padding-bottom: calc( 1 * ((15.3333% - 0.666667px) * 1) + 0px + 0px) !important;
}

.my-grid-tile-second {
  width: calc((20% - 0.75px) * 1 + 0px) !important;
  padding-top: calc((4.3333% - 0.666667px) * 1 + 0px) !important;
}




<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div class="container pt-24">
  <form class="example-form" [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()" ngNativeValidate>
    <div class="row mb-3 " *ngFor="let detailData of dataSource">
      <div class="col-12">
        <mat-card>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 font-weight-bold" style="margin-bottom: 30px; font-size: 16px;">
              {{ "ONBOARD_CUST_LABEL_CUSTOMER_INFO_SUMMARY" | translate }}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <label class="heading">{{'ONBOARD_CUST_LABEL_DILIGENT_APPLICATION_ID' | translate}}:</label
                        >
                        <span class="sub-data">{{detailData.applicationId}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label class="heading">
                            {{
                                "ONBOARD_CUST_LABEL_ONBOARDING_DATE"
                                    | translate
                            }}:</label
                        >
                        <span class="sub-data">{{detailData.dateInitiated}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label class="heading">
                            {{
                                "ONBOARD_CUST_LABEL_NEXT_REVIEW_DATE"
                                    | translate
                            }}:</label
                        >
                        <span class="sub-data">{{detailData.nextReviewDate}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" >
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="3:1">
                            <mat-grid-tile
                                *ngFor="let tile of customerDetails"
                                [colspan]="tile.cols"
                                [rowspan]="tile.rows"
                                [style.background]="tile.background"
                                [style.color]="tile.color"
                                [ngStyle]="{'font-size': tile.size + 'px'}"
                            >
                            <ng-container *ngIf="tile.type === 'text' else other">
                                {{ tile.text  | translate}}
                               </ng-container>
                               <ng-template #other >
                                {{
                                    tile.text?.localeData
                                        | localeLabel: (localeId$ | async)
                                }}
                            </ng-template>                            
                        </mat-grid-tile>
                        </mat-grid-list>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <mat-grid-list cols="6" rowHeight="2:1">
                            <mat-grid-tile
                                *ngFor="let tile of relationshipDetails"
                                [colspan]="tile.cols "
                                [rowspan]="tile.rows"
                                [style.background]="tile.background"
                                [style.color]="tile.color"
                                [ngStyle]="{'font-size': tile.size + 'px'}"
                            >
                            <ng-container *ngIf="tile.type === 'text' else other">
                            {{
                                tile.text  | translate
                            }}
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-template #other >
                            <ng-container *ngIf="tile.type === 'object' else otherData">
                                {{
                                    tile.text?.localeData
                                        | localeLabel: (localeId$ | async)
                                }}
                               </ng-container>
                               <ng-template #otherData >
                                
                            <ng-container *ngFor="let book of tile.text">
                             {{
                                 book?.localeData
                                     | localeLabel: (localeId$ | async)
                             }},
                            </ng-container>
                              
                         </ng-template>
                          
                     </ng-template>
                             
                             
                            </mat-grid-tile>
                        </mat-grid-list>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="row" >
                    <div
                        class="col-sm-8 font-weight-bold"
                        style="
                            margin-bottom: 30px;
                            margin-top: 30px;
                            font-size: 16px;
                        "
                    >
                        {{
                            "ONBOARD_CUST_LABEL_RISK_ASSESSMENT_SUMMARY"
                                | translate
                        }}
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="row mb-3" >
                    <div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="dueList.length">
                        <mat-grid-list [cols]="4" rowHeight="4:1"   class="my-grid-list-first">
                            <mat-grid-tile 
                                class="my-grid-tile-first"
                                *ngFor="let tile of dueList"
                                [colspan]="tile.cols"
                                [rowspan]="tile.rows"
                                [style.background]="tile.background"
                                [style.color]="tile.color"
                                [ngStyle]="{'font-size': tile.size + 'px'}"
                            >
                            {{
                                tile.text?.localeData
                                    | localeLabel: (localeId$ | async)
                            }} {{'LABEL_RISK' | translate}}
                            </mat-grid-tile>
                        </mat-grid-list>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
               
                
          
                    <!-- <div class="row mb-3" > -->
                      <div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="riskList.length">
                        <mat-grid-list [cols]="4" rowHeight="4:1"   class="my-grid-list-second">
                            <mat-grid-tile 
                                class="my-grid-tile-second"
                                *ngFor="let tile of riskList"
                                [colspan]="tile.cols"
                                [rowspan]="tile.rows"
                                [style.background]="tile.background"
                                [style.color]="tile.color"
                                [ngStyle]="{'font-size': tile.size + 'px'}"
                            >
                            {{
                                tile.text?.localeData
                                    | localeLabel: (localeId$ | async)
                            }} Risk
                            </mat-grid-tile>
                        </mat-grid-list>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
                    <div class="row" >
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <label class="heading"
                                >{{
                                    "ONBOARD_CUST_LABEL_WAIVER_APPLIED"
                                        | translate
                                }}:</label
                            >
                            <span style="margin-left: 10px;">
                                <mat-slide-toggle (click)="waiverAppliedToggle()"
                                    formControlName="waiverApplied"
                                ></mat-slide-toggle>
                            </span>
                            <span
                                class="sub-data"
                                *ngIf="formGroup.value.waiverApplied"
                            >
                                {{ "ONBOARD_CUST_LABEL_YES" | translate }}</span
                            >
                            <span
                                class="sub-data"
                                *ngIf="!formGroup.value.waiverApplied"
                            >
                                {{ "ONBOARD_CUST_LABEL_NO" | translate }}</span
                            >
                        </div>
                        <div
                            class="col-md-12"
                            *ngIf="formGroup.value.waiverApplied"
                        >
                            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                <mat-label>{{'ONBOARD_CUST_LABEL_COMMENTS'}}</mat-label>
                                <textarea formControlName="waiverComment" maxlength="3000"
                                    matInput
                                    placeholder=""
                                ></textarea>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </mat-card>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-3 pt-24">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                <div class="mr-2 flex-grow-1">
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="formGroup.value.waiverApplied" class="mr-2">
                    <button mat-raised-button class="custom-primary-button" [disabled]="!formGroup.valid" type="submit">
                        {{ "ONBOARD_CUST_BUTTON_SAVE" | translate }}
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="showCancle">
                    <button routerLink="/queue-config" mat-raised-button class="custom-primary-button">
                        {{ "ONBOARD_CUST_BUTTON_CANCEL" | translate }}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Here is the link for code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwh7ja?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

below is the image which is getting overlapped:

[image]

Green color is getting overlapped on red and yellow, div row should increase as the list gets increased,

Not able to fix the issue after many attempts.

This is the expected o/p

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this class from your css and that is done:

CSS

```
.my-grid-list-first {
    /*padding-bottom: calc(
        1 * ((15.3333% - 0.666667px) * 1) + 0px + 0px
    ) !important;*/
   
}
```

Comment: @vinuta, you wellcome. If it is used somewhere else, you can keep it but just remove the `!important` at the end, like this inline style will have the priority

Comment: but issue is same with second grid also div is not extending again overlapping the third gird

Comment: Ya i ll remove important

Comment: just do the same here: `.my-grid-list-second`

Comment: This is not in link here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwh7ja?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css
But I would suggest you to add a container maybe ?

Comment: Ya its not same but i thought it ll increase in that div, div class row is overlapping other div

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220846/discussion-between-maxigui-and-vinuta).

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by styling added in `app.component.css`.

Remove it should solve the issue.

BTW, you need re-add the padding according to your expected result.